# Is there a way/tool to check if an NFT or token address is malicious?

Tags: nft, tools

I want to know ways to find out suspicious activities/bad intentions programmed in NFT or token addresses. - elchuo160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can analyze address risks using two add-ons from [QuickNode Marketplace](https://www.quicknode.com/marketplace).

**1.** [MistTrack Address Risk Scores Add-on](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/address-risk-scores/).

Enable the [MistTrack Address Risk Scores Add-on](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/address-risk-scores/) on your QuickNode Ethereum RPC endpoint.

Then use this ethers v6 example:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
(async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("QuickNode_ETH_RPC_URL");
  const network = await provider.send(
    "mt_addressRiskScore",
    [{"chain": "ETH", "address": "ADDRESS_TO_BE_ANALYZED"}]
  );
  console.log(network);
})();
```

**2.** [Goplus Anti-fraud APIs Add-on](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/anti-fraud-apis).

Enable the [Goplus Anti-fraud APIs Add-on](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/anti-fraud-apis) on your QuickNode Ethereum RPC endpoint.

Then use this ethers v6 example:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
(async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("QuickNode_ETH_RPC_URL");
  const network = await provider.send(
    "gp_maliciousCheck",
    {"chain_id": "1", "address": "ADDRESS_TO_BE_ANALYZED"}
  );
  console.log(network);
})();
```